# WHY(Mechanics) jsx is not allowed in files with extension .js

Tags: reactjs, warnings, jsx, eslint

Why eslint throws such an error. there should be a reason for this. How is resolve is available through many articles though, couldn't explain the reason why rather than a fix. However it still works even if we rename it to .jsx or includes jsx in .js file extension. 
i'm a newbie in reactjs.

Answer (score 0):

JSX syntax is an extension to JavaScript, basically syntactic sugar for bulky `React.createElement` calls. JSX isn't valid JavaScript, so files that contain it conventionally have their own .jsx extension.

A setup can be configured to allow JSX in .js files but this isn't recommended. JSX should be additionally transformed to become valid JavaScript, for this reason it's beneficial to have separate .js and .jsx files.